# Angular UI dialog promise only fires when reopening dialog

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui

In the controller that opens the dialog I have:

```
$scope.openDialog = function () {
    var options = dialogOptionsFactory.build('/my/route/file.html', 'ChildController');
    var d = $dialog.dialog(options);
    d.open().then(function (result) {
        if (result) {

            // THIS DOESN'T FIRE UNTIL DIALOG IS REOPENED!
            $scope.myresult = result;

        }
    });
};
```

And in the dialog controller I have this (more or less):

```
listModule.controller('ChildController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'dialog', function ($scope, $rootScope, dialog) {

$scope.uploadComplete = function (ifrm) {
    var response = angular.element(ifrm).contents().find("body").text();
    var responseObj = eval("(" + response + ")"); //Parentheses needed to convert JSON to JS object.
    $scope.close(responseObj.Data);
};

$scope.close = function (result) {
    dialog.close(result);
};

}]);
```

Why doesn't the "then" promise execute until after I click to open the dialog again?

**Update** I added some more context as I think it might be relevant. I'm getting the data from the body of a hidden iframe. The promise fires just fine if I call `$scope.close()` directly. This makes me think it either has something to do with the iframe or that I'm passing back an object to dialog.close().

Comment: It could be because `dialogOptionsFactory` returns options asynchronously. Can you paste the code of `dialogOptionsFactory`?

Comment: It just returns an object. Nothing fancy there.

Comment: Why the dialog controller is ChildController not ParentController you specified in the build()?

Comment: The ParentController opens the dialog. The ChildController controls the dialog instance and should return data back to the ParentController.

Comment: Oh, I see what you're saying. I think that's a typo. I'll update it.

Comment: Are you calling `$scope.uploadComplete` from outside Angular (such as a DOM event or jQuery event) without using `$scope.$apply()`? If so, Angular will not be aware of the event.

Comment: Yes! Oh god thank you. You should put that as an answer so I can mark it as accepted. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, since sirhc was too modest to add his comment as an answer, I'll do it for him. :) The answer was to wrap the call in $scope.apply() to notify AngularJS right away.